# How to make Firefox WebExtension use microphone

Tags: javascript, firefox, microphone, firefox-addon-webextensions

I've been trying to make Firefox Extension which needs to have an ability for user to record a voice message.
I've made a web page which does work, but when I put the same code in the extension (with all the proper manifest.json changes), it doesn't work. It simply doesn't ask user for access to microphone.

I went through extension examples on Firefox site but I can't find the solution.

How can the extension, if it can, access users microphone?

Code:

```
window.addEventListener('load', initAudio);
```

And the **initAudio** function:

```
function initAudio() {
console.log("initAudio");
if (!navigator.getUserMedia)
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mediaDevices.mozGetUserMedia;
if (!navigator.cancelAnimationFrame)
    navigator.cancelAnimationFrame = navigator.webkitCancelAnimationFrame || navigator.mozCancelAnimationFrame;
if (!navigator.requestAnimationFrame)
    navigator.requestAnimationFrame = navigator.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || navigator.mozRequestAnimationFrame;

console.log("initAudio");
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(
    {
        "audio": {
            "mandatory": {
                "googEchoCancellation": "false",
                "googAutoGainControl": "false",
                "googNoiseSuppression": "false",
                "googHighpassFilter": "false"
            },
            "optional": []
        },
    }, gotStream, function (e) {
        console.log('Error getting audio');
        $("#controls").css("background", "red");
        console.log(e);
    });
}
```

I don't get console output

> Error getting audio

But I also don't get the console output from **gotStream** function.

Later, I have an HTML object which triggers the recording process:

```
    <img id="record" src="./res/icons/mic.png" class="">
```

with it's accompanying Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#record").click(function () {
    console.log("trigerred", this);
    toggleRecording(this);
});
});
```

function **toggleRecording** does get trigerred properly, but it can't work since Recorder object is not initalized (it gets initalized in **gotStream** function).

Here is the manifest.json file:

```
    {

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Speech",
  "version": "1.1",

  "description": "blank desript",
  "icons": {
    "16": "popup/res/icons/icon16.png",
    "32": "popup/res/icons/icon32.png",
    "48": "popup/res/icons/icon48.png",
    "128": "popup/res/icons/icon128.png"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "storage"
  ],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "32": "popup/res/icons/icon.png"
    },
    "default_title": "Speech",
    "default_popup": "popup/popup.html"
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": [
        "popup/res/script/jquery-3.2.1.js",
        "popup/res/script/audiodisplay.js",
        "popup/res/script/recorder.js",
        "popup/res/script/recorderWorker.js",
        "popup/res/script/resampler.js",
        "popup/res/script/main.js"
      ],
      "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ],
      "match_about_blank": true,
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ],

  "content_security_policy": [
    "script-src 'unsafe-inline'"
  ]


}
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: @Makyen is it better now? :)

Comment: It's an improvement, but it still needs more. We need to know in which JavaScript file the code you are showing exists. We need to know the source for the JavaScript libraries you are using. We can find jQuery, given that you state which version, but the others we have to guess at. The point of a [mcve] is so we can take the information/code in the question and be able to exactly duplicate the problem. That allows us to be able to find the issue and verify fixes. At *best* not having enough information in the question means we have to **guess** at what's going on. Here's some more info:

Comment: The reason that a [mcve] is required is that *we want to help*. It is **much** easier to help if we don't have to recreate any of the code needed to duplicate the problem. This is code that you already have. So, please help us to help you and provide a *complete* [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Without a [mcve], the amount of effort required to even begin to help you is **much** higher, which *significantly* reduces the number of people willing/able to help you. Even if we put out the extra effort, we have to **guess** at significant portions of what your problem might be.

Comment: A side issue to handle later, but: *Please* don't load jQuery and all those libraries into **every** page (`content_scripts` with your `matches`) unless you **need** to.  jQuery is 85kiB of minimized code and the others more. This is a significant burden with which to saddle *every single page*. What of those of us who have 100's of tabs open? The best thing to do is to load the *absolute minimum* needed to show just your UI's *initial* elements (without animation) & detect the user beginning to interact with it. If they do, *then* use `tabs.executeScript()` to load everything else needed.